# Which saint said a spiritual director should give his female directee books to read rather than meeting with her too frequently?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, sexuality

Which saint said a spiritual director should give his female directee books to read rather than meeting with her too frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St. Alphonsus of Liguori, [*True Spouse of Jesus Christ*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7683) ch. 10 "Detachment from Relatives and Other People", §2 "Detachment from seculars, and even from the sisters" ([EPUB](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/7683) ref:836.34):

> Father Peter Consolini of the Oratory has justly remarked that we should treat with holy people of a different sex as with the souls in purgatory, that is, at a distance, and without looking at them. Some religious have a strong desire of conversing with their spiritual Father because they imagine that his instructions will stimulate their fervor. But **what need is there of** such conversations, of such **long and familiar discourses? Have they not an abundant supply of spiritual books?** Have they not spiritual reading at table and at prayer? Have they not the benefit of sermons in the church? Without any of these the reading and observance of their Rules and Constitutions ought to be sufficient to make them saints.